# zclip not working inside table

Tags: jquery, zclip

I put my example code here
http://jsfiddle.net/8epWm/2/

I want to enable zClip on an element inside a table and it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Table elements have trouble with absolute positioning, and zClip uses absolute positioning to place the flash movie on top of the target element.

To work around this you can wrap a block level element (I used a `<div>`) around the target element, and give that `position: relative`.

Edit: See http://jsfiddle.net/dloewen/Ny9We/2/ for a working example.

Comment: thanks, that's genius!  Where would I find this sort of documentation about using zclip?

Comment: <span style="position: relative;"><a href="#" class="copy">copy</a></span>

Comment: if you use span make it display: inline-block or it doesn't work in saf+chrome

Comment: I had to add a rule `span div.zclip > embed {position:absolute}` to get the position totally correct

Comment: Have tried all this and does not work in a TD for chrome or ff

Comment: Thank you!! I spent hours going crazy until I found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might also add -- I found that if a z-index is set on the target element, it breaks the functionality of zClip (it's covering the flash element).