# Copy to clipboard with Zclip & Rails issue with ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeroclipboard, zclip

Using [Zclip-rails](https://github.com/HaNdTriX/zclip-rails) Gem which is a wrapper on top of [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) library. Code Below.

**View**

```
<table>
<% File.all.each do |file|
  <tr>
     <td> <%= text_field_tag :name, file.name , id: "text_#{file.id}" %> </td>
     <td> <%= link_to 'Copy to clipboard', 'javascript:void(0)', class: 'copy-to-clipboard', id: "text_#{file.id}" %></td>
    </tr>
</tr>
<%end>
<table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('a.copy-to-clipboard').zclip({
  copy: "this is the text to copy ankit",
  beforeCopy:function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
 }

});
```

The **Issue is** i am getting always a the same id on click of all links made for copy to clipboard For eg: 'text_1'.  What i am expecting is that with different rows i should get different id's on click of copy to clipboard.

Any thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: Please, paste result code to jsfiddle and show it.

Comment: Actually, i do it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tVZNm/1/ and everything looks fine. So, show your compiled html code.

Comment: @mr.The. thanks for creating the fiddle..  i have updated it http://jsfiddle.net/tVZNm/5/ .  I need to copy the cells which are there as 11.jpgboo & 12.jpgboo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done: http://jsfiddle.net/tVZNm/10/

Here is problem with table css position: zclip flash wrapper appears on wrong position(at top, left corner of table).
So i add wrapper div for links, with `posotion: relative;`.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673681/zclip-not-working-inside-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317150/cant-get-zclip-to-work) threads for details.